# Find a geometric solution for a equilateral tringle within 3 circles

Tags: geometry

For the task of constructing an equilateral triangle with a vertex on each of three concentric circles (the subject of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4016802/409)), I found a solution on: http://mathafou.free.fr/pbg_en/sol113.html, which is hard to understand.

[image]

Red triangle is the solution. Quoting from the reference:

> With point P as center, draw circles (A), (B) and (C) with radii a,b,c. We can fix A anywhere on circle (A).

So in the graphic is A fixed on the bottom of the outter circle.
A circle is drawn with the radius AP and cuts at M.

> The locus of C is then (C). B is deduced from C by rotating with center A and angle π/3.

There is no B in the graph. Just confusing.

> The locus of B is then circle (C') image of (C) using this rotation. But it is also (B) from definition. Point B is then the intersection point of (B) and (C').

Why is the circle (C') with middle point drawn here?

> Point C is then deduced by inverse rotation.

Ok. We have B1 and now we rotate back 60 degrees to have C.

> There are two intersection points B1 and B2 giving the two triangles obtained from analytic solution.
> Only one of them contains point P.

Yes, B1, but why? "We must have angle ABP < π/3"

Please, I need some help.

Comment: I have found a similar solution here: http://blog.mathoffthegrid.com/2019/03/the-curious-case-of-equilateral.html

Comment: similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653623/how-to-construct-an-equilateral-triangle-on-2-concentric-circles

Comment: @endgameyourgame they havnt found a solution.

Comment: A, C, B1, and M look like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#cite_note-wilson-2

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Experimental approach[image]

$r_1=40, r_2=55, r_3=70$, in this case the difference between radii is equal.

The locus of center of triangle ABC , Q is a circle center on O and radius OQ and we have:

$OQ\approx \frac{\sqrt{40+55+70}+\sqrt{40}+\sqrt{55}+\sqrt{70}}2\approx 17.48$

This value is close to $17.88$ shown in figure.

[image]

In this figure the difference of radii is not equal. $r_1=47, r_2=60, r_3=80$ and we have:

$OQ\approx\frac{\sqrt{47+60+80}+\sqrt{47}+\sqrt{60}+\sqrt{80}}2\approx 18.6$

This value is close to $20.8$ shown in figure. So for a rough drawing:

1- calculate OQ and draw a circle $r=OQ$ center on O.

2- take an arbitrary point on this circle (Q). this is the center of triangle. In a particular case one of altitudes of triangle crosses the center O. So draw a line connecting O and Q, this line is perpendicular bisector of BC.

3- The angles both QB and QC make with OQ is $60^o$.By drawing the rays of these angles you get vertices B and C on circles with radii $r_2$ and $r_1$ respectively. Vertex A is the intersection of OQ with third circle with radius $r_3$.

May be by analytic geometry we can find a more accurate formula for $OQ$ in terms of $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$.