# Can I Draw an Equilateral Triangle with one corner on these 3 concentric circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Basically, I have a geometry problem where I have to draw an equilateral triangle and place each of it's corners on different concentric circles. My question is two-fold: can this be done in principle, and can I draw a equilateral triangle with a corner on each of the three specific concentric circles I need to draw it on.

The three specific circles I am trying to build an equilateral triangle with have the equations:

1. (x^2+y^2)^0.5=(0.5^2^(1/3))
2. (x^2+y^2)^0.5=(0.25^2^(1/3))
3. (x^2+y^2)^0.5=((1/9)^2^(1/3))

How would I figure out the cartesian coordinates of the corners of a triangle with one corner on each of these concentric circles?

Edit: What is not the same about this question
The question of which this may be a duplicate according to some, does answer the fact that this can be done in principle, but it does not answer whether or not I can make an equilateral triangle with these three specific circles or give me the tools to figure that out myself. I need to know how to figure out if three concentric circles can form an equilateral triangle, not just that it is possible.

Comment: "*whether or not I can make an equilateral triangle with these three specific circles*" $\;-\;$ I added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4368875/291201) under the other question which addresses that.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/333476/305862)